# For all natural numbers of $n$, prove by induction that $15 \mid (4^{2n+1} + 5^{2n+1} + 6^{2n+1})$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

What I have so far:

We will prove by induction. Our induction predicate $P(n)$ is $15 \mid (4^{2n+1} + 5^{2n+1} + 6^{2n+1})$.

Base Case: $n = 0$: $P(0)$ is $15 \mid (4^{2(0)+1}+5^{2(0)+1}+6^{2(0)+1})$. $4+5+6 = 15$, so $P(0)$ is true.

Inductive Step: $n \geq 0$: Let the natural number of $n$ be arbitrary and assume $P(n)$ is true. Now we show $P(n+1)$ is true, where $P(n+1)$ is $15 \mid (4^{2(n+1)+1} + 5^{2(n+1)+1} + 6^{2(n+1)+1})$.
$4^{2(n+1)+1} + 5^{2(n+1)+1} + 6^{2(n+1)+1} = 4^{2n+3} + 5^{2n+3} + 6^{2n+3}$.

That's all I have. I am unable to finish

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You meant to write $4 + 5 + 6 = 15$.

Comment: Yes I went ahead and fixed that error

Comment: Hint: it's easier to check mod 3 and mod 5.

Comment: With $f(n)=(4^{2n+1} + 5^{2n+1} + 6^{2n+1})$, we get $f(n+1)-f(n)=30 \cdot (2 \cdot 16^n + 4 \cdot 25^n + 7 \cdot 36^n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $4^{2k+1} + 5^{2k+1} + 6^{2k+1} \equiv 0 \pmod {15}$ **(1)**

Let $4^{2(k+1)+1} + 5^{2(k+1)+1} + 6^{2(k+1)+1} \equiv x \pmod {15}$

Then $4^{2k+3} + 5^{2k+3} + 6^{2k+3} \equiv x \pmod {15}$

$16*4^{2k+1} + 25*5^{2k+1} + 36*6^{2k+1} \equiv x \pmod {15}$

$4^{2k+1} + 10*5^{2k+1} + 6*6^{2k+1} \equiv x \pmod {15}$ **(2)**

subtract **(1)** from **(2)** to get

$9*5^{2k+1} + 5*6^{2k+1} \equiv x \pmod {15}$,
and since $9*5^{2k+1}$ has a factor of both $3$ and $5$, it makes $15$ a factor of $9*5^{2k+1}$, and this is also true for $5*6^{2k+1}$ , meaning $x=0$.

I  doubt this is the most efficient solution but it is one.

Comment: Not sure how you suddenly jump from the second to last expression to the final expression.

Comment: 16 mod 15 is congruent to 1 mod 15, 25 mod 15 congruent to 10 mod 15, 36 mod 15 is congruent to 6 mod 15.

Answer (score 2):

You want to try to express $4^{2n+3}+ 5^{2n+3} + 6^{2n+3}$ in terms of $4^{2n+1}+ 5^{2n+1} + 6^{2n+1}$ so that you can bring in the induction hypothesis. One way is convert the indices back to $2n+1$:
\begin{align}
4^{2n+3}+ 5^{2n+3} + 6^{2n+3} &= 16\times4^{2n+1}+ 25\times5^{2n+1} + 36 \times 6^{2n+1} \\
&= 16(4^{2n+1}+ 5^{2n+1} + 6^{2n+1}) + 9 \times 5^{2n+1} + 20 \times 6^{2n+1}
\end{align}
The first term is divisible by $15$ by the induction hypothesis, the second and third term are both divisible by $15$, so you are done.

Answer (score 1):

There are already answers that use induction, so I will provide another answer using modular arithmetic.

First of all looking at the expression modulo $3$ we have
$$4^{2n+1} + 5^{2n+1} + 6^{2n+1} \equiv 1^{2n+1} + (-1)^{2n+1} + 0^{2n+1} \equiv 1 - 1 + 0 \equiv 0\pmod 3$$

Then looking at the expression modulo $5$ we have
$$4^{2n+1} + 5^{2n+1} + 6^{2n+1} \equiv (-1)^{2n+1} + 0^{2n+1} + 1^{2n+1} \equiv -1 + 0 + 1 \equiv 0\pmod 5$$

This shows that the expression is divisible by both $3$ and $5$, so it is also divisible by $15$.